# Indeterminate progressbar in listview

Tags: android, listview, scroll, progress-bar

I'm trying to create a list that shows an indeterminate progress bar as the last entry while it's fetching more data.  I can show the bar and get/add the data, but scrolling up and down while it's loading causes multiple progress bars to show up.

I have a ListActivity that uses an ArrayAdapter.  Each row has a layout as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/textlines" android:padding="2dip">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rowContent">
    <TextView android:height="20sp" android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/search_display" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="16sp" android:layout_height="20sp" android:gravity="left" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/rowSpinner"
    android:padding="3px" android:gravity="center" android:visibility="gone">
    <ProgressBar android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The ListView has an OnScrollListener with the following onScroll method.

```
public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
{
  // detect if last item is visible
  if ((visibleItemCount < totalItemCount)
      && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount))
  {
    if (false == scrollTaskRunning)
    {
      scrollTaskRunning = true;
      getMoreData(totalItemCount);
    }
  }
}
```

getMoreData invokes an AsyncTask that gets some more data to add to adapter.  In its onPreExecute I call showSpinner() --

```
private void showSpinner()
{
  // nothing to do if there's already a spinner visible
  if (isSpinVisible == true) return;

  // hide the progress spinner
  if (0 < lvList.getChildCount())
  {
    View vRow = lvList.getChildAt(lvList.getChildCount() - 1);
    vRow.findViewById(R.id.rowContent).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    vRow.findViewById(R.id.rowSpinner).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
  isSpinVisible = true;
}
```

and in its onPostExecute/onCancelled I call hideSpinner() which is the same code, except checking the isSpinVisible flag the other way, and GONE and VISIBLE swapped.  The swapping code, so far as I can tell, only gets called once, but multiple entries in the last show up with the progress bar visible if you scroll up and down.

I tried doing this instead for hideSpinner() --

```
private void hideSpinner()
{
  // nothing to do if there's no spinner visible
  if (isSpinVisible == false) return;

  // show the progress spinner
  int iChildCount = lvList.getChildCount();
  if (0 < lvList.getChildCount())
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < iChildCount; i++)
    {
      View vRow = lvList.getChildAt(iChildCount);
      if (null != vRow)
      {
        vRow.findViewById(R.id.rowContent).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vRow.findViewById(R.id.rowSpinner).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
    }
  }
  else if (null != pbSearch)
  {
    pbSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
  isSpinVisible = false;
}
```

but vRow is null, and some of the progress bars still show up.  How do I fix this?  Alternatively, is there a better way to do this?  (I thought I might be able to do something with my ArrayAdapter's `getView()` method, but I couldn't work it out.)

---

**ETA**: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318648/listviews-contents-scrambled-on-scroll/4319987#4319987) seems to explain the problem I'm having, but knowing that hasn't helped me find a way around it.

---

**ETA2**: I tried doing this:

```
final LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                     getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
aapSearchResults = new ArrayAdapter<ParsedXML>(this, R.layout.search_row, saData)
{
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    View row;

    // get the view
    if (null == convertView)
    {
      row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_row, null);
    }
    else
    {
      row = convertView;
    }

    // bind the data to the view
    TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.search_display);
    tv.setText(getItem(position).name);

    // show data, hide spinner
    row.findViewById(R.id.rowContent).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    row.findViewById(R.id.rowSpinner).setVisibility(View.GONE); 

    // if the current position is the last, and a task is running,
    // show the progress bar        
    if (taskRunning && (position == this.getCount()-1))
    {
      row.findViewById(R.id.rowContent).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      row.findViewById(R.id.rowSpinner).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);            
    }


    return row;
  }
};
lvList.setAdapter(aapSearchResults);
```

but I'm clearly making a logic error still, because sometimes scrolling up and down now gets me blank entries.  (Is it because the count has changed?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you should never touch the children of a `ListView` directly. In fact, after they leave your adapter's `getView()` nest, you should consider them to be fully independent and entirely divorced from your direct control. The only way you can control them is by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` and letting the ListView make new ones.

To get around your problem, do something like:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter[…]{
    //[…]

    private boolean mIsLoading = false;

    public void setIsLoading(boolean isLoading){
       if (mIsLoading != isLoading){
          mIsLoading = isLoading;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
    }

    @Override 
    public int getCount(){
       return super.getCount() + (isLoading ? 1 : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (mIsLoading && position == (getCount() - 1)){
            //return your progress view goes here. Ensure that it has the ID R.id.progress;

        }else{
            if (convertView != null && convertView.getId() == R.id.progress){
                convertView = null;
            }
            return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a BaseAdapter instead. It automatically loads more elements when the last one on the list is shown.