# Load Bitmaps/images in ListView Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-adapter, android-bitmap

I'm trying to add images in a ListView which has an ArrayAdapter. Fyi, the toList() is a conversion from iterator to a list of the given DBObject.

I override the `View getView()` and set a textview and an image.

```
private static class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DBObject> {      

    public EventAdapter(Context context, int resource, Iterable<DBObject> events) {
        super(context, resource, toList(events));           
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;               
        LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());                              
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.adapter_event_list, null);

        DBObject event = getItem(position);

        if (event != null) {

            //Get the logo if any
            if( ((DBObject)event.get("events")).containsField("logo") ){      

                String logoURL = ((DBObject)((DBObject)event.get("events")).get("logo")).get("0").toString();
                ImageView eventLogo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.eventLogoList);
                new setLogo().execute(logoURL, eventLogo);

            }               
            TextView title= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eventTitleList);             
            title.setText( ((DBObject)event.get("events")).get("title").toString() );               

        }

        return v;
    }

    protected static <T> List<T> toList( Iterable<T> objects ) {
        final ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        for( T t : objects ) list.add(t);
        return list;
    }
    //setLogo() method here. See below
 }
```

The text in the textview is fine. However the images are getting messed up. They seem to load in wrong places in the list. The route of the code is: 1)Get from the DB (async) 2)populate the ListView 3) while populating load each image(second async).

Here is the `setLogo()` AsyncTask which is inside the `EventAdapter` above:

```
private class setLogo extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,Bitmap>{

        ImageView eventLogo = null;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object...params) {
            try{
                Bitmap eventImage = downloadBitmap((String) params[0]);
                eventLogo =  (ImageView) params[1];
                return eventImage;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap eventImage) {
            if(eventImage!=null && eventLogo!=null){                    
                eventLogo.setImageBitmap(eventImage);
            }
        }  

}
```

I did so (using an Async) which I believe is the correct way to load images from urls. I saw this [post on multithreading](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) and from which I borrowed the `downloadBitmap()` method.

As explained above the images are loaded in wrong places of the ListView. What can be a robust way to load them?

Also the idea to pass the `v.findViewById(R.id.eventLogoList)` inside the AsyncTask is that the program will distinguish each adapter's ImageView but it seems it doesn't.

---

**Update**

After following the problem that is causing this mix I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3874639/1447885).

I altered my code in order to check if the `if` is causing the problem.

```
//Get the logo if any               
if( ((DBObject)event.get("events")).containsField("logo") ){                        
        String logoURL = ((DBObject)((DBObject)event.get("events")).get("logo")).get("0").toString();
        ImageView eventLogo = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.eventLogoList);

        //new setLogo().execute(logoURL, eventLogo);   

        TextView title= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.eventTitleList);
        title.setText( "Shit happens" );    

    }
```

Let's say I have 40 items. The `Shit happens` is set on the fields that a `logo` field exists. If I scroll down/up the order changes and the text gets messed up. It is because the stack created inside the loop is small than the maximum of the list..I guess... I am still struggling.

PS: I found [this easy library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to load images asynchronously instead of DYI stuff.

---

**Update 2**

I added an else with a static url. Because of the time it take to the image to load they are still misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

I would really go for a good library like Picasso.
It will handle all the hard part for you and it's very well written.
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Thanks for the library, I tried it however the content is still mixed up.