# Android ListFragment scrambles the order of elements that aren't initially rendered

Tags: java, android, android-listview

So I'm working on a fairly simplistic SMS app to teach myself Android, and I seem to have run into the same problem described in this thread: [ListView in ArrayAdapter order get's mixed up when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955218/listview-in-arrayadapter-order-gets-mixed-up-when-scrolling)

Unfortunately, the answer posted there doesn't seem to be working for me. I've been looking at this for a long time now, and I'm stumped. Note that since this is an SMS app, I'm using two different layouts, depending on who sent the message.

Also, in by debugging, I have found that the messages that I pass in my ArrayList are in the correct order, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. Any help would be amazing.

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

public MessageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CryptoMessage> messages){
    super(context, 0, messages);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 *
 * @param position
 * @param convertView
 * @param parent
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CryptoMessage current = (CryptoMessage) getItem(position);

    if(convertView == null){
        if(current.isSent()){
            //This is message that the user sent. Inflate the view for a sent message.
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sent_message, parent, false);
        }
        else{
            //Otherwise, this is a message that the user received. Inflate the view for a received message.
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recieved_message, parent, false);
        }
    }

    if(current.isSent()){
        //The current message is a sent message. Get the resources from the sent view.
        TextView body = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sentMessageText);
        TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sentMessageDate);

        //Populate the data.
        if(body != null) {
            body.setText(current.getMessage());
        }
        if(date != null) {
            date.setText(current.getDate());
        }
    }
    else{
        TextView body = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recievedMessageText);
        TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recievedTimestampText);

        if(body != null) {
            body.setText(current.getMessage());
        }
        if(date != null) {
            date.setText(current.getDate());
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem #1: Never use `LayoutInflater.from()` for creating a UI for an activity or fragment. Always call something more specific, like `getLayoutInflater()` on the `Activity`. As it stands, your themes will be ignored.

Problem #2: If you are going to use multiple different layouts for rows, you *must* override `getViewTypeCount()` to return the number of layouts (in your case, 2). Also, you *must* override `getItemViewType()` to return a value (in your case, 0 or 1), indicating which type of row will be used for the supplied `position`. In your case, that would be based on `isSent()`.

Problem #3: Get rid of the `body != null` and `date != null`. If you do not get your widgets for your rows, you want to crash during development, so you can start determining *why* you did not get your widgets. In this case, had you left those checks off, you would be crashing with `NullPointerExceptions`, indicating that you did not find the widgets, and perhaps would have had an easier time finding out what went wrong.

Comment: Perfect! That works beautifully! I guess the tutorial I was using wasn't that great.