# How to get the GridView position while its checkbox item is checked?

Tags: android, gridview, checkbox

I have a custom GridView with `checkbox`, `imageView` and `textView`.
 In the `gridViewAdapter.getView()`, i have used rows and holder to initialise the values for checkbox, imageView and textview.

Now when I click on checkbox, I need to fetch the position of that gridView item so I can move the image from it's position to another position in a gridView.

I tried like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.cb=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //here with this checkbox which just got clicked,
                    // i want to access its gridview position or holder index
                    // so i can get access to the image

                }
            });
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    ImageItem item = (ImageItem)dataArraylist.get(position);
    holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
   // holder.cb.setChecked(item.isSelected());

    return row;
}
    public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView imageTitle;
    public ImageView image;
    public CheckBox cb;
}
```

UPDATED: ok the parameter "position" of getView function works. 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){}. 
But now when I select checkbox in the first view , the position of checkbox is returned correctly. 
but when i scroll down to next view, the positions of checkbox is random. how to resolve this?

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {       

    final int pos=position;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.cb=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        if(flag) {
            holder.cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("MYLOG", "position: "+pos);
                    ImageItem tempObj;
                    ImageItem item = clickedArraylist.get(pos);
                   if(item.isSelected())
                        item.setSelected(false);
                    else
                        item.setSelected(true);

                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
        }

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    }
        ImageItem item = clickedArraylist.get(position);
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        holder.cb.setChecked(item.isSelected());

    return convertView;
}


    public static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView image;
    public CheckBox cb;
}
```

Comment: Get it from adapter

Comment: ok the parameter "position" of getView function works.                        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){}.  But now when I select checkbox in the first view , the position of checkbox is returned correctly. but when i scroll down to next view, the positions of checkbox is random. how to resolve this?

Comment: it is not automatic.. only when user checked the checkbox, it will check someother item bcoz the position is random now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG this worked: first answer of the below link [ListView in ArrayAdapter order get's mixed up when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955218/listview-in-arrayadapter-order-gets-mixed-up-when-scrolling)

just need to close the if(convertView==null) right after inflating the view and remove the else part of it

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple. Here's my code which I have implemented in one of my apps.

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (dataTaken.contains(position)) {
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
                // checkBox.setClickable(false);
                final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Another topic already being taken", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar.setAction("Ok", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        snackbar.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                        .show();
            } else {
                if (isChecked) {
                    number.add(position);
                } else if (!isChecked) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < number.size(); m++) {
                        if (number.get(m).equals(position)) {
                            number.remove(m);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Once you are done with that you can access the list using this fuction from the adapter class

```
public ArrayList<Integer> item() {
    return number;
}
```

Now from your Activity class call

```
variable = adapter.item();
```

Done!!

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be to set a `tag` to the `view` and get it when it is clicked, something like below:

```
holder.cb.setTag(pos);
holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = (int) v.getTag();

                ImageItem tempObj;
                ImageItem item = clickedArraylist.get(position);
                ...
        });
```

And do whatever you want with the position then. Please let me know if you have trouble implementing it.